# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'file') in prisma

Tags: reactjs, express, file-upload, prisma, prisma2

I'm trying to create an input form that involves files. for the backend ny I use prism and express orm, when I do a test with postmant the data is successful but when I integrate with the client it doesn't work with the description "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'img')"

`

```
const test = async (req = request, res = response) => {
    try {
        const { nama } = req.body;
        //handle file upload
        const file = await req.files.img;
        const fileSize = file.data.length;
        const ext = path.extname(file.name);
        const fileName = file.md5 + ext;
        const url = `${req.protocol}://${req.get("host")}/testing/${fileName}`;
        const allowType = [".png", ".jpg", ".jpeg"];
        if (!allowType.includes(ext.toLowerCase()))
            return res.status(422).json({
                message: "Harus bertype JPG,JPEG,PNG",
            });
        if (fileSize > 5000000)
            return res.status(422).json({
                message: "File terlalu besar, max 5 MB",
            });
        file.mv(`./public/testing/${fileName}`, async (err) => {
            if (err) return res.status(500).json({ message: err.message });

            const testpost = await Test.create({
                data: {
                    nama: nama,
                    img: fileName,
                    url: url,
                },
            });
            res.status(201).json({
                status: "succes",
                query: testpost,
            });
        });
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({
            succes: false,
            error: error.message,
        });
    }
};
```

//for client

```
const submit = (data) => {
        let formdata = new FormData();
        formdata.append("nama", data.nama);
        formdata.append("img", data.img[0]);

        let object = {};
        formdata.forEach(function (value, key) {
            object[key] = value;
        });

        axios
            .post(`http://localhost:5000/testing`, {
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
                },
                body: object,
            })
            .then((res) => {
                console.log(res);
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.error(err);
            });
    };
```

`

Comment: Can you log the value of the file variable and confirm if it's not undefined?